# Running VBA code of auto re-filter, when cell values change in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets, 1 with changing values Y/N in one column, and another sheet vlookuping some columns of the first sheet, including the Y/N column. I have had the Y/N column in sheet 2 filtered to "Y", so whenever I change in sheet 1, I have to click "Reapply" on filter. I tried to write both VBA codes to reapply and another one to call the "reapply" when value is change but no luck.

(((This is the Reapply filter, "Summary" is sheet2))))

```
Sub ReapplyFilter()  
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter  
End Sub
```

((This is for the sheet1 "Index Concept", where I change Y/N)))

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  
    If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Index Concept").Range("AM24:AM64")) Is Nothing Then Run Sheet1.ReapplyFilter  
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it give you an error ? or it does nothing ?

Comment: This `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` should work fine

Comment: @Mikku It doesn't give error, but I have to hit run macro after every time I do changes. I need it to run automatically with any change in that "Index Concept" sheet range.